# Mercurial forest extension: not found

Tags: mercurial, ubuntu-11.04, ubuntu

I've enabled the Mercurial forest extension:

hgext.forest=

But the command 'fclone' is still not found.

I guess the extension is not installed.

How can I install the forest extension on Kubuntu 11.04? (I'm using Mercurial v2.2.1)

/usr/share/mercurial contains the hgk and hgext.rc scripts, so is this the hgext directory?

How can I get the forest script? I searched in  KPackageKit but I couldn't find it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Mercurial wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ForestExtension):

**This third-party extension does not appear to be actively maintained. Consider using *subrepos* instead.
This extension is not being distributed along with Mercurial.**

Comment: Is this compatible with the forest extension? The OpenJFX project is using the forest extension.

Comment: And there is also https://code.google.com/p/hgnested/
How does this relate to the forest extension and the subrepos extension?

Comment: No idea. But on the wiki page linked above, there is a link to external repos for forks of the forest extension, so it's easy to install your own copy of one of them and try it out.  Why not ask the project which one they are using?